# Why is Ubuntu saying I have 4.1 GB of storage when I actually have 128 GB?

Tags: partitioning

I'm currently trying to install Ubuntu 23.04 on my laptop, but when I try to install it, I get an error saying that I don't have 20 GB of space or above, but I have 128 GB of space and over 100 GB of free space. And it says i have 4.1 GB of storage on Ubuntu.

Comment: Because you are making a mistake? w/o some more details it is difficult to suggest something else  :)  You need unallocated space, not free. You also need to pick the correct partition or disk   The installer will be correct when it says 4.1 :) :)

Comment: What is the partition that is Ubuntu root - eg sda1...sda2 etc?

Comment: Can you provide the output of 'sudo blkid'? It'll help to see the device partition table.

Answer (score 0):

128GB of total space, over 100GB free space.

Should I assume, there is already some system?

Should I assume, that system is on one partition, that takes whole 128GB?

Should I assume, you didn't decrease size of partition, to free space for Ubuntu?

Should I assume, that other system is Windows?

Should I assume, you want to install Ubuntu in dual boot?

Then https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-support-how-to-re-partition-without-destroying-the-data-c3d64de0-4672-b21f-de4e-b4908fb35ae3

And after you have "black" empty space, that is at least 20GB, you can boot Ubuntu and install it. I recommend making at least 40GB of unallocated space.

Comment: Clearly the asker did not provide enough information in the question to rely on.

Comment: Clearly the 'asker 'isn't genuinely interested in solving his problem.